# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Gene1'

Tags: python-3.x

I cannot get rid of this error. Can anyone please help?

Here is the code:
[The first part of the code which is normalizing the function is working but when add the 2nd part, I got the following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgXHC.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdimicro/Desktop/B573/9:22/test1.py", line 
  96, in <module>
    a.append(int(x1[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Gene1'
```

Thank you

Comment: Post code here, not a screenshot, and please make it a [mre] otherwise we cannot help you much more than what I said below.  In this case, it's highly relevant what the variable `i` is when you split it and hence what is the line in `Test.txt`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means the `x1[0]` is the string "Gene1" and it cannot be converted to a integer number. Either the input file doesn't match your code, or maybe you want to append the string intead, i.e.:

```
a.append(x1[0])
```